# How to make extend property for HTML Select server control?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want to make an extend property of control `<asp:DropdownList  ID="ddlUser" runat="server" />`.

Can I create a `.SelectedValue` property for `<select id="selectUser" runat="server" />`
so I can use that property in C# so I can use like `ddlUser.SelectedValue` .

There are some property need to extend in HTML `<select runat="server">` control.

`selectUser.Value` (need to extended with .SelectedValue property)

```
ddlUser.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Your welcome, I only altered the grammar/spelling (and removed the tags form the title). When you next post a question try not to add tags to your title, it's why we have a tagging system. ;)

Comment: You have to use inheritance and implement it by hand on your shoulder.

Comment: @MarcoAlves can you please write the example with sample code..

Answer (score 0):

You can't do extension properties in C# 3.0 or 4.0.
However, you can do the following

Define a helper class as extension

```
public static class SelectExtensionHelper
{
    public static string SelectedValue(this System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect select)
    {
        return select.Items[select.SelectedIndex].ToString();
    }
}
```

while in the ASP page:

```
<select id="selectUser" runat="server" >
        <option id="op1id" value="val1id"> option1 </option>
        <option id="op2id" value="val2id"> option2 </option>
        <option id="op3id" value="val3id"> option3 </option>
    </select>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Button" />
```

Use this where you need:

```
Response.Write("The value is:"+ selectUser.SelectedValue() + " Done");
```

You can use Extension methods instead ;)

Comment: I seen that you are new over stackoverflow.. huhh